# How to provide sprint results to large array of clients?

Tags: scrum, agile

I work as scrum master for all of our corporate systems related to ServiceNow. Unlike many projects, we have a ton of different (internal) clients. Finance/Legal/Facilities/Contract and the list goes on. We have large scale projects that we surge on and continue to support and update for some clients, we have 1 off issues for others and everything in between. Some of these larger projects are interconnected or are owned by multiple internal departments.

A problem we are having is that many of these groups aren't fully aware of what we are getting completed. The changes simply pop-up for them on prod after our scheduled deployments and they may not realize all of the value we are delivering. I know that the sprint review is a common way to allow the client the work your team has completed at the end of each sprint but we have so many clients, many who aren't interested in much of the other work we complete. I fear that marathon reviews/demos will take up too much time.

In this context, how can I effectively let my various internal clients know all of the work we completed so they can see the value we deliver and provide feedback?

Comment: While there are things you can do as a project manager or Scrum Master, this is really a corporate communications or IT alignment problem. At the scale you're describing, any solution needs to include senior management buy-in and a sensitivity to organizational politics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a real challenge.

Some suggestions that may help:

- Have several short demos sandwiched together in the sprint review. Publish an agenda prior to the sprint review which includes times so that stakeholders can attend just for the bits they are interested in.
- Consider video taping your demos and splitting them up in to the various features that were delivered in each sprint. Make the videos available online and provide a method for stakeholders to watch them and provide feedback.
- Publish a sprint review "news letter" containing details of what work was done and distribute it to all stakeholders. Provide a method for feedback.
- Demo as you go along in the sprint. As each piece of functionality is completed, let the relevant stakeholders know that they can come over for a quick demo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can send out a survey to all your stakeholders every time you do a release. This encourages more engagement than simply an email. There are a few very nice tools available to make surveys more fun.

Perhaps you can have a small banner at the top of the system (if this is possible) with a link to a page which explains the value delivered in the latest version.